# Apache 2.4 time out per path basis

Tags: apache, timeout

I've been using the TimeOut directive from Apache core settings to limit the timeout for http requests:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

My question is, is there a way to set the time out on a per domain/path basis? The thing is, I have an Apache instance which redirects all the requests to multiple applications. I would like to have different timeouts based on the path. For example:

```
www.myapps.com/myappA/services/serviceA -> 30 secs timeout
www.myapps.com/myappB/services/serviceB -> 60 secs timeout
```

The way I use TimeOut currently applies for all the domains and paths.